# Weak convergence for symmetric closed operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $ X $ be a Hilbert space, $ A_n, A $ be symmetric closed operators on $ X $ which satisfies 
\begin{equation*}
{s.g.-\lim}_{n \to \infty} A_n = A \quad (\textrm{Strong graph convergence})
\end{equation*}
For $ x_n \in \mathcal{N}(A_n) $, if $ x_n \stackrel{w}{\longrightarrow} x $, can we determine that $ x \in \mathcal{D}(A) $?